# How to hide awstats url parameters

Tags: apache, htaccess, virtualhost, httpd.conf, awstats

currently in order to access statistics on my site I access this link:

```
www.example.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=awstatsconffile.org
```

all is working fine, but what I want to achieve is simply this:

```
www.example.com/stats/
```

I've created the "sites" directory and inside I've created the .htaccess file but without success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this with mod_rewrite.

Inside your root directory (generally public_html), place a .htaccess file with the following content:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

#Redirecting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^www\.mysite\.org\/stats\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) www\.mysite\.org\/awstats\/awstats\.pl\?config=awstatsconffile\.org - [L]
```

I'm not good at regex, so you may need to escape/unescape some characters, but that's the way.

Comment: Not Working !!!! . . . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following in the document root's .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^stats/$ /awstats/awstats.pl?config=awstatsconffile.org [L]
```

This will internally rewrite requests for `/stats/` to the above URL.